# How to I return a "on the fly" table? Mismatch seems to make no sense

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am getting the error: *return type mismatch in function declared to return record*

I have used pg_typeof for every column returned to ensure the types were correct, but I still can't make it work.

I need the return query so that I can build another function that would READ the result and call another function (PL/PGSQL) to create the sample people. It can't be a simple INSERT as there are many rules to be followed that is already done by this other FUNCTION called create_person (Not shown here)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_last_name" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_first_name" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_nickname" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_honorific" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_suffix" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_stop_word" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_email_domain" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_document_type" CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "common_year_of_birth" CASCADE;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _get_sample_data;

CREATE TABLE "common_last_name" (
    "last_name" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "ratio" numeric NOT NULL,
    "last_name_phonetic" text NOT NULL,
    "last_name_phonetic_alt" text,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_first_name" (
    "first_name" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "ratio" numeric NOT NULL,
    "first_name_phonetic" text NOT NULL,
    "first_name_phonetic_alt" text,
    "genre" text,
    "genre_m_f_percentage" int,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_nickname" (
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    "name_phonetic" text NOT NULL,
    "name_phonetic_alt" text NOT NULL,
    "nickname" text NOT NULL,
    "nickname_phonetic" text NOT NULL,
    "nickname_phonetic_alt" text NOT NULL,
    "genre" text NOT NULL,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_honorific" (
    "honorific" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_suffix" (
    "suffix" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_stop_word" (
    "stop_word" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_email_domain" (
    "domain_name" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "ratio" numeric NOT NULL,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_document_type" (
    "country_iso_document_type" text PRIMARY KEY,
    "ratio" numeric NOT NULL,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "common_year_of_birth" (
    "year" int,
    "ratio" numeric NOT NULL,
    "inserted_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);

---------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _get_sample_data(p_number_of_records INT) 
RETURNS TABLE(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT, email TEXT, phone TEXT, document TEXT, date_of_birth TIMESTAMP) 
AS $$
WITH first_names_weighted AS 
(
    SELECT
        first_name,
        SUM(ratio) OVER (
    ORDER BY
        first_name) - ratio AS lower_bound,
        SUM(ratio) OVER (
    ORDER BY
        first_name) AS upper_bound 
    FROM
        common_first_name 
),
last_names_weighted AS 
(
    SELECT
        last_name,
        SUM(ratio) OVER (
    ORDER BY
        last_name) - ratio AS lower_bound,
        SUM(ratio) OVER (
    ORDER BY
        last_name) AS upper_bound 
    FROM
        common_last_name 
),
email_domain_weighted AS 
(
    SELECT
        domain_name,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        domain_name ) - ratio AS lower_bound,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        domain_name ) AS upper_bound 
    FROM
        common_email_domain 
),
document_type_weighted AS 
(
    SELECT
        country_iso_document_type,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        country_iso_document_type ) - ratio AS lower_bound,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        country_iso_document_type ) AS upper_bound 
    FROM
        common_document_type 
),
year_of_birth_weighted AS 
(
    SELECT
        YEAR,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        YEAR ) - ratio AS lower_bound,
        SUM(ratio) OVER ( 
    ORDER BY
        YEAR ) AS upper_bound 
    FROM
        common_year_of_birth 
),
randoms AS 
(
    SELECT
        random() * ( 
        SELECT
            SUM(ratio) 
        FROM
            common_first_name ) AS f_random,
            random() * ( 
            SELECT
                SUM(ratio) 
            FROM
                common_last_name ) AS l_random,
                random() * ( 
                SELECT
                    SUM(ratio) 
                FROM
                    common_email_domain ) AS e_random,
                    random() * ( 
                    SELECT
                        SUM(ratio) 
                    FROM
                        common_document_type ) AS d_random,
                        random() * ( 
                        SELECT
                            SUM(ratio) 
                        FROM
                            common_year_of_birth ) AS y_random 
                        FROM
                            generate_series(1, p_number_of_records ) 
)
SELECT
    --r, 
    first_name AS first_name,
    last_name AS last_name,
    LOWER( SUBSTRING( first_name, 1, 2 + (random() * (length(first_name) - 2))::INTEGER) || SUBSTRING( last_name, 1, 2 + (random() * (length(last_name) - 2))::INTEGER) || '@' || domain_name ) AS email,
    '+1 ' || lpad(round(random() * 999)::text, 3, '0') || ' ' || lpad(round(random() * 999)::text, 3, '0') || ' ' || lpad(round(random() * 9999)::text, 4, '0') AS phone,
    CASE
        WHEN
            POSITION('.sin' IN country_iso_document_type) > 1 
        THEN
            country_iso_document_type || '.' || lpad((round(random() * 999))::TEXT, 3, '0') || '-' || lpad((round(random() * 999))::TEXT, 3, '0') || '-' || lpad((round(random() * 999))::TEXT, 3, '0') 
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN
                    POSITION('.driver' IN country_iso_document_type) > 1 
                THEN
                    country_iso_document_type || '.' || chr((65 + random()*25)::INT) || lpad(CAST(round(random() * 99999) AS text), 5, '0') || '-' || lpad((round(random() * 99999))::TEXT, 5, '0') || '-' || lpad((round(random() * 99999))::TEXT, 5, '0') 
                ELSE
                    CASE
                        WHEN
                            POSITION('.passport' IN country_iso_document_type) > 1 
                        THEN
                            country_iso_document_type || '.' || chr((65 + random()*25)::INT) || chr((65 + random()*25)::INT) || lpad((round(random() * 999999999999))::TEXT, 12, '0') 
                        ELSE
                            NULL 
                    END
            END
    END
    AS document,
    make_date(YEAR, (round(1 + random() * 11))::INTEGER, 1) + make_interval(days => (round(1 + random() * 30))::INTEGER) AS dob 
FROM
    randoms r 
    CROSS JOIN
        first_names_weighted f 
    CROSS JOIN
        last_names_weighted l 
    CROSS JOIN
        email_domain_weighted e 
    CROSS JOIN
        document_type_weighted d 
    CROSS JOIN
        year_of_birth_weighted y 
WHERE
    f.lower_bound <= r.f_random 
    AND r.f_random <= f.upper_bound 
    AND l.lower_bound <= r.l_random 
    AND r.l_random <= l.upper_bound 
    AND e.lower_bound <= r.e_random 
    AND r.e_random <= e.upper_bound 
    AND d.lower_bound <= r.d_random 
    AND r.d_random <= d.upper_bound 
    AND y.lower_bound <= r.y_random 
    AND r.y_random <= y.upper_bound;
END;
$$ language sql;


-- ***SAMPLE DATA
--Common email domains
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('gmail.com', 200);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('yahoo.com', 20);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('outlook.com', 20);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('hotmail.com', 20);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('icloud.com', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('yahoo.ca', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('shaw.ca', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('live.ca', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('aol.com', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('protonmal.com', 4);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('zoho.com', 4);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('startmail.com', 4);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('thexyz.com', 2);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('gmial.com', 10);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('yaho.com', 5);
INSERT INTO common_email_domain(domain_name, ratio) VALUES ('outloock.com', 5);

--Common year of birth
--1.7 ratio 18-24 age
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-18, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-19, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-20, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-21, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-22, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-23, 17);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-24, 17);
--5.2 ratio 25-44 age
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-25, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-26, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-27, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-28, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-29, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-30, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-31, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-32, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-33, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-34, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-35, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-36, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-37, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-38, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-39, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-40, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-41, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-42, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-43, 52);
INSERT INTO common_year_of_birth(year, ratio) VALUES (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)-44, 52);

--Common document types
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('', 1000);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('ca.sin', 100);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('ca.driver-licence', 100);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('in.passport', 8);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('us.passport', 6);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('cn.passport', 4);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('mx.passport', 4);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('br.passport', 4);
INSERT INTO common_document_type(country_iso_document_type, ratio) VALUES ('ca.passport', 1);

--Common First Names
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('John', 0.01827302261, dmetaphone('John'), dmetaphone_alt('John'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('David', 0.01546078785, dmetaphone('David'), dmetaphone_alt('David'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Robert', 0.01443493568, dmetaphone('Robert'), dmetaphone_alt('Robert'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Michael', 0.01203178307, dmetaphone('Michael'), dmetaphone_alt('Michael'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Paul', 0.009156650734, dmetaphone('Paul'), dmetaphone_alt('Paul'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Richard', 0.007790220995, dmetaphone('Richard'), dmetaphone_alt('Richard'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('James', 0.007687311565, dmetaphone('James'), dmetaphone_alt('James'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Peter', 0.00749865699, dmetaphone('Peter'), dmetaphone_alt('Peter'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('William', 0.006330570112, dmetaphone('William'), dmetaphone_alt('William'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Brian', 0.006272669254, dmetaphone('Brian'), dmetaphone_alt('Brian'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Mary', 0.006226325682, dmetaphone('Mary'), dmetaphone_alt('Mary'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Linda', 0.005831280103, dmetaphone('Linda'), dmetaphone_alt('Linda'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Daniel', 0.00570003053, dmetaphone('Daniel'), dmetaphone_alt('Daniel'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Mark', 0.005683095101, dmetaphone('Mark'), dmetaphone_alt('Mark'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Chris', 0.005489481954, dmetaphone('Chris'), dmetaphone_alt('Chris'), 'm', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Karen', 0.005429559525, dmetaphone('Karen'), dmetaphone_alt('Karen'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Jennifer', 0.005307616808, dmetaphone('Jennifer'), dmetaphone_alt('Jennifer'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Lisa', 0.005023833946, dmetaphone('Lisa'), dmetaphone_alt('Lisa'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Susan', 0.004946709088, dmetaphone('Susan'), dmetaphone_alt('Susan'), 'f', 100); 
INSERT INTO common_first_name(first_name, ratio, first_name_phonetic, first_name_phonetic_alt, genre, genre_m_f_percentage) VALUES ('Michel', 0.00491550823, dmetaphone('Michel'), dmetaphone_alt('Michel'), 'm', 100); 

--Common Last Names
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Smith',dmetaphone('Smith'), dmetaphone_alt('Smith'), 0.01321048057);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Brown',dmetaphone('Brown'), dmetaphone_alt('Brown'), 0.007484346222);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Tremblay',dmetaphone('Tremblay'), dmetaphone_alt('Tremblay'), 0.007333709135);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Martin',dmetaphone('Martin'), dmetaphone_alt('Martin'), 0.006303244211);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Roy',dmetaphone('Roy'), dmetaphone_alt('Roy'), 0.006216409597);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Gagnon',dmetaphone('Gagnon'), dmetaphone_alt('Gagnon'), 0.005852226737);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Lee',dmetaphone('Lee'), dmetaphone_alt('Lee'), 0.00573562222);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Wilson',dmetaphone('Wilson'), dmetaphone_alt('Wilson'), 0.005690520472);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Johnson',dmetaphone('Johnson'), dmetaphone_alt('Johnson'), 0.005465286746);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('MacDonald',dmetaphone('MacDonald'), dmetaphone_alt('MacDonald'), 0.005415372312);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Taylor',dmetaphone('Taylor'), dmetaphone_alt('Taylor'), 0.004917534274);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Campbell',dmetaphone('Campbell'), dmetaphone_alt('Campbell'), 0.004886114306);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Anderson',dmetaphone('Anderson'), dmetaphone_alt('Anderson'), 0.004837781184);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Jones',dmetaphone('Jones'), dmetaphone_alt('Jones'), 0.004689619193);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Leblanc',dmetaphone('Leblanc'), dmetaphone_alt('Leblanc'), 0.004670574706);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Cote',dmetaphone('Cote'), dmetaphone_alt('Cote'), 0.004568820763);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Williams',dmetaphone('Williams'), dmetaphone_alt('Williams'), 0.004381538507);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Miller',dmetaphone('Miller'), dmetaphone_alt('Miller'), 0.004340080651);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Thompson',dmetaphone('Thompson'), dmetaphone_alt('Thompson'), 0.004331349063);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Gauthier',dmetaphone('Gauthier'), dmetaphone_alt('Gauthier'), 0.004196181326);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('White',dmetaphone('White'), dmetaphone_alt('White'), 0.003903226226);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Morin',dmetaphone('Morin'), dmetaphone_alt('Morin'), 0.003866718561);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Wong',dmetaphone('Wong'), dmetaphone_alt('Wong'), 0.003792740695);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Young',dmetaphone('Young'), dmetaphone_alt('Young'), 0.003712231326);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Bouchard',dmetaphone('Bouchard'), dmetaphone_alt('Bouchard'), 0.003682461422);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Scott',dmetaphone('Scott'), dmetaphone_alt('Scott'), 0.003515461202);
INSERT INTO common_last_name(last_name, last_name_phonetic, last_name_phonetic_alt, ratio) VALUES ('Stewart',dmetaphone('Stewart'), dmetaphone_alt('Stewart'), 0.003489747706);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have not worked through all  of this, but I did see a spurious `END;` at end of function. That is `plpgsql` thing(where it needs to be paired with a `BEGIN`) not a `sql` function one.

Comment: Well removing the `END;` allowed the `CREATE FUNCTION` to succeed without `ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record`. I could not go any further then that as the `INSERT`(s) depend on missing functions.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks so much. If you prefer to put this as the answer, I'll mark it as the answer. I am new to PostgreSQL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
END;
$$ language sql;
```

`END;` is used in `plpgsql` in conjunction with `BEGIN` to mark blocks in the code. `sql` language functions do not use this syntax as they do not have blocks. The presence of `END;` results in this error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "_get_sample_data"
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer!